# Spock UnitTest, Too few invocations, but exact same invocation in "Unmatched invocations" list

Tags: groovy, spock

I am writing a Unit Test for some Code of mine that calculates Time.
I'm using SQL.date as an input and convert it to Calendar for the calculation. (Yes I know Joda would be better).

My test is as following:

```
def objectOrgUnit = Stub(ConOrgUnit)

def notification

def setup(){
    objectOrgUnit = Stub(ConOrgUnit) {
        getLogicalName() >> "Multimedia"
    }
}

def "CreateNotification creates Notification with correctly caluclated dates"() {
    given:
    def date = new java.sql.Date(2020-1900,4,1)

    def not = new NotificationGenerator()
    def contract = GroovyMock(GenericBean) {
        getCtrInsuranceDateToDat() >> date
    }
    def vocs = GroovyStub(ControlledVocabularyAccess) {
        getNodesByInstanceAndName('TasStatusVgr', 'open') >> [Stub(ControlledVocabularyNode)]
        getNodesByInstanceAndName('TasTypeVgr', 'TYPE') >> [Stub(ControlledVocabularyNode)]
    }

    def newNotification = GroovyMock(GenericBean) {
        getTasContract02Ref() >> GroovyMock(GenericBean)
        getTasSendEmailGrp() >> GroovyMock(GenericBean)
    }

    def dataAccess = GroovyStub(DataAccess) {
        createObject("Task") >> newNotification
    }
    def orgUnitAdminService = Stub(OrgUnitAdminServiceAccess) {
        readUsingLogicalName("org") >> objectOrgUnit
    }
    not.metaClass.vocs = vocs
    not.metaClass.dataAccess = dataAccess
    not.metaClass.orgUnitAdminService = orgUnitAdminService
    when:
    notification = not.createNotification(contract, 2, "REASON", "TYPE", "TESTMAIL@MAIL.COM", "org")
    then:
    1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineDat(2020-02-01)
    1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineToDat(2020-02-01)
}
```

when run, it gives me the error:

```
1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineDat(2020-02-01)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineDat(2020-02-01)
```

So it looks like it would be correct?
I also tried testing for "date" which doesn't work either.

The code itself is this (partly):

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.setTime(contract.CtrInsuranceDateToDat)
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1 * (months + 1))
    taskNotification.TasDeadlineDat = new java.sql.Date(c.getTime().getTime())
    taskNotification.TasDeadlineToDat = new java.sql.Date(c.getTime().getTime())
```

Comment: Unfortunately your test is not very readable and at the same time I cannot copy and run it either because the classes under test are all missing. This is a little bit of a problem if you are hoping for helpful answers. So maybe you want to improve the question and with it your chances to get a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I cannot run your test, but I think I spotted it:

```groovy
then:
1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineDat(2020-02-01)
1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineToDat(2020-02-01)
```

`2020-02-01` is just a subtraction `2020 - 2 - 1` or `2017`, not a date, neither a simple Java date nor an SQL date (which is a subclass of the Java date, so be careful).

I think what you rather want is something like:

```groovy
given:
def expectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2020-02-01")

// ...

then:
1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineDat(expectedDate)
1 * newNotification.setTasDeadlineToDat(expectedDate)
```

Now you are really comparing dates. It works for comparing `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` because the latter does not override the `equals(..)` method of the former.